# Does Swift have any concurrency safety guarantees?

Tags: swift, concurrency, functional-programming

Does swift have any concurrency safety guarantees like the data race guarantees of Rust, or decent functional concurrency support?

Answer (score 0):

No swift doesn't have any of those grantees when using the normal blocks so you'd need to implement a locking mechanism by yourself to guarantee data integrity and solve race conditions yourself.

Here's a sample code which you can try yourself in a playground and you can see the results are conforming to any of the expected outputs out of the loops as both queues use the same resource interchangeably. Hope this helped.

```
import Cocoa

var x = 1

let q1 = DispatchQueue(label: "FirstQueue")
let q2 = DispatchQueue(label: "SecondQueue")

q1.async {
    for i in 0...999 {
        print("First Queue working \(Thread.current)")
        x += 1
    }
    print(x)
}

q2.async {
    for i in 0...999 {
        print("Second queue working \(Thread.current)")
        x -= 1
    }
    print(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of [Swift 5.5](https://www.swift.org/blog/swift-5.5-released/), Swift added support for Concurrency.  One of the features of Swift Concurrency is [Actors](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0306-actors.md) which gives compiler support to prevent data races. The wwdc video where Actors were introduced is [here](https://developers.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133/).